# Clarifai API for Local Image

Tags: node.js, image-recognition, clarifai

I'm trying to make a nodejs application that captures an image from the computer's webcam, and then uses Clarifai API to recognize what is in that picture. I haven't figured out how to do that for local images, however, as the method I'm using, the one presented in the 'Getting Started' section of the API, only works with urls, and not local file paths.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same,but couldn't figure it out,
Did you get it ???

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse it works with localfile also but with client side java script SDK. (not with node js). for client side clarifai SDk add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.clarifai.com/js/clarifai-latest.js"></script>
```

in html header and inti sdk using

```
const app = new Clarifai.App({
 apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
});
```

by adding sdk you got Clarifai as global varible for example go to offical clarifai  demo https://www.clarifai.com/demo and open console and type  Clarifai and got magic,

[image]
if done this magic then now it's time to go https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/